# Shiny app that opens other shiny apps

Tags: r, shiny

Currently I have a pretty big modularized Shiny applications. It basically consists of 6 modules that do different things and I access them through a dashboard sidebar.

However, as a result everything in the Shiny app has to be wrapped in ns() in order to work properly. This results in a lot of difficulties in some cases.

Thus, I wanted to ask whether it is possible to create one starting shiny application, which has buttons that open other shiny applications. My idea is to put each module in a standalone application (or group them in 3 standalone applications with 2 modules inside each). The starting app being a Markdown file works fine as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Do the shiny apps need to pass information between each other? (i.e. load data into one that another can use?) if not, you can use a simple html link.

Comment: how would that work? what would the link be to? I could do it with data loaders in each module if it's easier to do it that way/

Comment: Are you using shinyserver? Or running these apps through Rstudio/R command line? I am guessing the latter in which case you are going to have a lot of trouble. In the former you would have an app URL that you could easily link to.

Comment: No, no - I'm not using shinyserver - I was looking more of a solution (or just knowing if it's possible) through running an app from R Studio. Should have mentioned that probably, but totally forgot about the shinyserver way to do it. Thank you very much for the answers still!